# Underline the text of the ToggleButton OnMouseOver in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, onmouseover, togglebutton

How can I `Underline` the Text of the `ToggleButton` when mouse is over it? I'm using the below code but nothing happens when I hover the mouse.

```
<Style x:Key="BaseToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 3 0 3"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Border">
                    <Image Width="13" Height="13" Source="{StaticResource ColumnsLayoutMiniIcon}">
                    </Image>
                    <Border x:Name="Content"
                            Padding="4 2 4 2"
                            Margin="5 0 0 0">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />

                    </Border>                        
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Background" Value="#acacac"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is odd because this part of the code works:

```
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
```

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751235/cant-get-underline-to-show-up-when-triggered) which shows an interesting way to achieve underline for a ContentPresenter as a whole by encasing the ContentPresenter inside a TextBlock and then using the TextBlock as the target of the trigger, thus underlining the entire ContentPresenter.

Comment: Thanks the link you provided helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the `TextDecorations="Underline"` in Style, then you need to use the `TextBlock` instead of `ContentPresenter` (or any other control).

Yes, it is dependency property, but it is not [*`attached`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963221/behavior-of-dependencyproperty-with-regards-to-multiple-frameworkelement-instanc) proprety, is plain dependency property defined and exposed by `TextBlock` and it is is perfectly visible in [`ILSpy`](http://ilspy.net):

```
TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty = Inline.TextDecorationsProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TextBlock),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new FreezableDefaultValueFactory(TextDecorationCollection.Empty), 
                                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Therefore, this property can only be set to control the type of `TextBlock`.